# Pass Data to next vue

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-router

I'm a React Native beginner and I would like to know how to pass the TorchesMigRefroidiesAir data to the next view for corresponding postes.
I don't know how to do it I tried with getParam but without success. Can you help me please? thank you.

```
export default class PostesMig extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const ref = firebase.database().ref("PostesMig");
    ref.on("value", (snapshot) => {
      this.setState({
        postes: snapshot.val(),
        loading: false,
      });
    });
  }
  goToTorches = () => this.props.navigation.navigate("Torches");
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.postes);
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>Chargement...</Text>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large"></ActivityIndicator>
        </View>
      );
    }
    const list = this.state.postes;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={list}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.CodeCommun.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View>
              <Card title={item.DesignationAS400}>
                <Text style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
                  Code Commun : {item.CodeCommun}
                </Text>
                <Text style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
                  Reference Fournisseur : {item.RefFournisseur}
                </Text>
                {console.log(item.TorchesMigRefroidiesAir)}
                <Button
                  onPress={this.goToTorches}
                  buttonStyle={{
                    borderRadius: 0,
                    marginLeft: 0,
                    marginRight: 0,
                    marginBottom: 0,
                  }}
                  title="VOIR LES TORCHES"
                />
              </Card>
            </View>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The page where I would like to retrieve the TorchesMIGRefroidiesAir from the corresponding Postes :

```
export default class Torches extends React.Component {
    constructor () {
        super()
        this.state = {
            loading: true
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const ref = firebase.database().ref('PostesMig');
        ref.on('value', snapshot => {
            let results = [];
            snapshot.forEach((child) => {
            results.push(child.val().TorchesMigRefroidiesAir);
            });
            this.setState({
                postes : results,
                loading: false
            })
        })
    }
    goToTorches = () => this.props.navigation.navigate('Torches')
    render() {
        if(this.state.loading) {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text>Chargement...</Text>
                    <ActivityIndicator size="large"></ActivityIndicator>
                </View>
            )
        }  
        const list = this.state.postes
        let newData = list.flat(1)
        newData = newData.filter(function (el) {
            return el != null;
          });
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                data={newData}
                keyExtractor={(item, i) => 'D' + i.toString()}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <View>
                    <Card
                    title={item.DesignationAS400}
                    >
                    <Text style={{marginBottom: 10}}>
                        Code Commun : {item.CodeCommun}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={{marginBottom: 10}}>
                        Reference Fournisseur : {item.RefFournisseur}
                    </Text>
                    </Card>
                </View>
                )}
            />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it with as an extra params on the navigate function:

```
goToTorches = (item) => this.props.navigation.navigate('Torches', {torches: item})
```

You will need to change `onPress={this.goToTorches}` for `onPress={()=>this.goToTorches(item)}`.

Use this code to retrieve the value

```
const { torches } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
```

Comment: Thank you I used your solution but I get this error message: react native invariant violation: Tries to get frame for out of range index NAN

Comment: Check the value that you are passing to your FlatList for the data props. I am guessing it isn't an array. A break point right before should tell you rightaway.